# SDDM not logging in, Garuda Linux(Arch Based), KDE plasma 5.25

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, sddm

SDDM accepts my password, starts a X11 session then crashes back to SDDM.

before i got this problem, my pc booted to a SDDM black screen with a cursor, used tty2 to log in and reinstall SDDM.

to replicate the problem:

- `sudo pacman -R sddm-kcm sddm`
- `sudo pacman -Syu sddm-kcm sddm`

Solutions tried:

1. removing ~/.Xauthority
2. copying /etc/pam.d from live usb
3. using tty2 and startX command to login and change SDDM theme to breeze

right now i am using lxdm but i would like to find a way to go back to SDDM

Comment: Without checking the logs, one could only guess. Please edit your question with the relevant output of `journalctl -f` after a crash occurs